# How to properly use firebase-firestore async calls

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on my Final Year Project and I am really stuck on the decision should I use callbacks or coroutines of Kotlin. I created separate Module for the firebase where all its operations are done there weather its data retrieval or any other functionalities.

the problem is that whenever I return the user from the function  it return `null`  due than I understand it due to the async calls and after that I used call back for it like this:

```
fun getUserAsModel(callback: (User) -> Unit) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid?.let {
        firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
            .document(it)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { it1 ->
                val user = it1.toObject(User::class.java)?.let { it2 ->
                    callback(it2)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "In userModel()->", it)
                it.stackTrace
            }
    }
}
```

But I see in many forms that I should  I use coroutines and now I  am using this approach but it does not work:

```
fun getUser () : User? {
    var user:User? = null
    val collection = firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
    val document = collection.document(FirebaseAuthRepository().getCurrentUserId())
    try {
        scope.launch {
            val snapshot = document.get().await()
            user = snapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
        }
    } catch (e:FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "In getUser() -> " ,e)
        e.stackTrace
    }
    return user
}
```

I am still stuck because every time I use `getUser()` I need to launch the scope of coroutines and this is really makes the code juncky.

I would like to know about your solution how should I properly implement this. Thanks

Comment: it really doesn't matter to be honest, if you're done and looking to improve your overall code then you can try out different things, sure, but don't waste time on "improving" code which already works. do you have any issues with the callback approach ? if not, just use that, spend your time on improving your project instead of on worrying about minor details

Comment: `getUser` should probably be a suspend function entirely in order for it to work like you want it to, at this point it seems to make sense that it returns null

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you for your prompt response. the reason that I am worried is that it's really slow async calls and my supervisor is constantly telling me why it's slow. the main reason is that when my app launch by requirement I need to check the users phone number in firestore before user process to screen so here the call is really slow to get the user and check  the number.

Comment: unfortunately, slow api calls are just part of the job :) you could perhaps investigate into caching data locally or just ensure that you have proper loading indicators in your app to show what's going on, but there isn't much you can do to improve that, neither coroutines nor callbacks would really have enough of a significant impact to improve this

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) might help you understand the differences between a few ways of reading data from Firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recreating the same problem you had with the asynchronous call, since a coroutine is launched asynchronously. The correct way to do it with a coroutine is to make it a suspend function and directly return the user without launching another coroutine inside this function.

The function should look like this:

```
suspend fun getUser () : User? {
    val collection = firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
    val document = collection.document(FirebaseAuthRepository().getCurrentUserId())
    return try { 
        val snapshot = document.get().await()
        snapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
    } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "In getUser() -> ", e)
        null
    }
}
```

Callbacks versus coroutines is a matter of preference. Coroutines are not trivial to learn, but once you do, your code will be cleaner-looking and easier to follow.

Comment: Keep in mind, this means you have to launch a coroutine somewhere else to be able to call this function, and you must use the result inside that coroutine.

Comment: I created this ->   val scope = CoroutineScope(CoroutineName("LoginFragment")) and than called the  suspend function. and also is there any way to make this call sync instead of async  so it returns the value  fast ?

Comment: No, you can't make Firebase faster at fetching values. Otherwise they would have made it fast to begin with. It's an IO operation, so it is always going to be something you cannot safely call synchronously on the main thread. Also, you probably should not be creating your own coroutine scope. Use either the preexisting `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` so your coroutine can be automatically canceled when the associated component reaches end of life.

Comment: I don't use Firebase, so I'm not sure, but maybe you can cache the User and save relevant data to disk and restore it if the session is still valid to load it a bit faster when possible. That would still be an IO operation, but reading from a file is usually faster than fetching from the Internet.

Comment: can ask how to use lifecycleScope?

Comment: for now  i  use the above scope  like this:      scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val user = UserRepository().getUser()
                user?.let {
                    Log.w(TAG, "---In UserRepository().getUserSync :hasAPhone -- ") // Todo: Remove
                    hideProgress()
                    updateUi1(firebaseUser, it.phone.isNotEmpty())
                }
            }

Comment: btw thank you I just replace scope with lifecycleScope. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Coroutines are not something you can experiment with and use without understanding. You need to read through the documentation to understand them fully before using them. You can read about how to use `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` in the Android documentation. Since this is fetching from Firebase, you almost certainly should be doing this in a ViewModel and using `viewModelScope`, not `lifecycleScope`, for this if your design is clean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242553/discussion-between-mohammad-khalid-shehab-and-tenfour04).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `callbackflow`

```
fun getUserAsModel():Flow<User?> {
        return callbackFlow {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid?.let {
                firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
                    .document(it)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { it1 ->
                        val user = it1.toObject(User::class.java)
                        trySend(user)
                        
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.e(TAG, "In userModel()->", it)
                        it.stackTrace
                        cancel(it)
                    }
                awaitClose { close() }
            }
        }

    }
```